# SQL query - select rows with at least two duplicate values

Tags: sql, select, group-by

Here is my sample table:

```
|"id","singlesaleid","quantity"
-------------------------------------
| 1,   "00278e0f",    37
| 2,   "00278e0f",    38
| 3,   "002ebd2e",    37
| 4,   "00380783",    37
| 5,   "003b3c35",    37
| 6,   "003b3c35",    38
| 7,   "0042170b",    38
| 8,   "00421b89",    37
| 9,   "00421b89",    38
| 10,  "00587f02",    37
| 11,  "00799433",    38
| 12,  "00799433",    37
```

How to make select to choose and group only this rows that in singlesaleid column have at least two duplicates values?

Result should be:

```
|"id","singlesaleid","quantity"
-------------------------------------
| 1,   "00278e0f",      37
| 6,   "003b3c35",      38
| 9,   "00421b89",      38
| 12,  "00799433",      37
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  singlesaleid, MIN(quantity) min_val
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY singlesaleid
            HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) b a.singlesaleid = b.singlesaleid AND
            a.quantity = b.Min_Val
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9be65/2)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek it's because the OP did have exactly tell how the value will be selected. By the way, it yield correct value from a row above.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek see this records, how did the OP choose between record `1 and 2` and `11 and 12`? through the lowest quantity right? which is different from record `5 and 6` and `8 and 9` because he selects the highest quantity.

Comment: Yes, that's right. There is no way of getting desired output, because there is no pattern there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want any of the records(only one) of only those `singlesaleid's` which has atleast 2 duplicates then try below code..

```
select * from table where rowid in 
(select min(rowid) from table
group by singlesaleid
having count(*)>=2)
```

Comment: which rdbms are you using ?? The above query will work in `Oracle`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use option with [EXISTS()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188336.aspx) operator. Although, I don't quite understand, what row shall be selected from group, in request selected a row with MAX(t2.Id)

```
SELECT *
FROM Tablename t1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM Tablename t2
              WHERE t1.singlesaleid = t2.singlesaleid
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND MAX(t2.Id) = t1.id
              )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb399/1)